# MIT OCW 6.00's Chicken McNugget program... again

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.5

I have spent a little while reading previous questions/answers about MIT OpenCourseWare 6.00's problem set regarding a program for determining the maximum *unattainable* number of chicken McNuggets in packs of 6, 9, and 20. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble integrating those answers into the code I've tried to make on my own.

First, here is the actual phrasing of the problem set that I'm trying to write code for:

> ... we can write an exhaustive search to find the largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity. The format of the search should probably follow this outline:
> • Hypothesize possible instances of numbers of McNuggets that cannot be purchased exactly, starting with 1
> • For each possible instance, called n, test if there exists non-negative integers a, b, and c, such that
> 6a+9b+20c = n. (This can be done by looking at all feasible combinations of a, b, and c)
> • If not, n cannot be bought in exact quantity, save n
> • When you have found six consecutive values of n that in fact pass the test of having an exact solution, the last answer that was saved (not the last value of n that had a solution) is the correct answer, since you know by the theorem that any amount larger can also be bought in exact quantity.
> Write an iterative program that finds the largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity. Your program should print the answer in the following format (where the correct number is provided in place of (n)): “Largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity: (n)”
> Hint: your program should follow the outline above.

(The theorem referenced basically says that once you have six permissible values for n in a row, you can add six on to them indefinitely and there will be no more impermissible values for n.)

This is my code:

```
n = 1                                  #set first value for trying to solve the equation
savedn = []                            #list for holding values of n w/ no integer solution
consecutivecount = 0
while consecutivecount < 6:
    for a in range(0,n):
        for b in range(0,n):
            for c in range(0,n):
                if 6*a + 9*b + 20*c == n:
                    consecutivecount += 1
                else:
                    #NOW A MIRACLE HAPPENS!!!
                    consecutivecount = 0      #resets consecutivecount value to zero
                    savedn += [n]             #adds current value of n to list
                n += 1                        #increases value of n to continue test loop
print 'Largest amount of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity:',str(savedn[-1])+'.'
```

My difficulties:

1. As you can see, I am stuck in the very middle of this, where indicated. I see other questions/answers for this problem using bools, but I'm not sure why anyone is going about it that way. Do I actually *have* to use bools, though? And why? Basically I would appreciate help figuring out an efficient operation to perform for the "else."
2. I'm not sure if I am really using the savedn list correctly. When I have run test segments of this code, I know I am clearly adding values to the list, but some confirmation that this is the correct way to use "savedn += [n]" would be nice.

I still know VERY few commands and I have very rusty math skills, so as with my last question from this course, please assume I'm an idiot in responding. On the other hand, if what I'm attempting above is just hopelessly off the mark, feel free to clearly suggest how I should start from scratch.

Thanks and apologies for length— the other discussions of this question just didn't seem thorough enough to be useful. (And apologies also that this requires Python 2.5.)

Comment: What exactly is your problem with "using bools"? Setting a "flag variable" to True or False to keep track of whether some condition is true or false is a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Sure, there are almost always ways to restructure your code so that isn't necessary, but often that restructuring can be pretty drastic.

Comment: I dont understand the problem text ... but it sounds kinda cool a hint you know that a can only go upto at most `n//6` ... likewise b to `n//9` and c only to `n//20` ... that should help alot with speed issues

Comment: in answer to 2. yes as long as that line executes it should append to `savedn`

Comment: @abarnert I don't have an actual problem with using bools; my trouble is that in my study I have not yet encountered an explanation of how to properly use them, so I have been first trying to work with what I know. If the fastest/most elegant way to code this algorithm would involve bools, I am all ears, but I figured I'd first tax people less by presenting the basic conditionals/iteratives I created and finding out how to make them work as-is. Unless there's actually no way to do this as I've begun it.

Comment: @devonjones: "Using bools" is trivial. If you know how to use ints—which are values that can be any number—then you know how to use bools—which are values that can be either True or False and nothing else. There's really nothing complicated to learn here. In fact, you already _are_ using bools in every `if` statement you write: `6*a + 9*b + 20*c == n` is either True, in which case the "if" part happens, or False, in which case the "else" part happens.

Comment: @abarnert I definitely understand what you're saying. Let me try rephrasing my difficulty. I know what bools functionally do, but so far I am more familiar with the syntax for using ints/floaters or strings, hence I incidentally wrote my code this way. Then, as you said above, restructuring between something with vs. without bools can be drastic, so rather than restructure my code altogether, I would first prefer to know what addition/change to my code would incorporate the approach I already used. As an educational bonus, of course, I would not mind learning a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Suppose the question was "find a solution of what to order to get 'n' McNuggets"? You have the core of that, and could solve that question with something like:

```
solution = (0,0,0)
for a in range(0,n):
    for b in range(0,n):
        for c in range(0,n):
            if 6*a + 9*b + 20*c == n:
                solution = (a,b,c)
```

Now, all you need to do is surround this with bookkeeping like you have:

```
while consecutivecount < 6:
    solution = (0,0,0)
    # ** find a solution like above
    if solution == (0,0,0):
        consecutivecount = 0      #resets consecutivecount value to zero
        savedn += [n]             #adds current value of n to list
    else:
        consecutivecount += 1
    n += 1                        #increases value of n to continue test loop
```

So you look for a solution for `n` and if you found one, you count up the consecutivecount, and if you didn't find one, you save off another unattainable number (and reset consecutivecount).  In either case, time to go on to another `n`.

Comment: This seems likely to be very helpful. Unfortunately my IDLE decided to crash on me and I don't want to plague anyone with a help request for that problem in this thread, so I will have to try this later. But thank you.

Comment: As an educational exercise, you can change it to use a boolean to record whether you find a solution or not, and skip recording the actual solution integers (which are never used).

Comment: This is (a) incorrect - your ranges have an off-by-1 error, although this will only every matter if you ever encounter a pack size of 1 - and (b) really wretchedly inefficient. Doing `for a in range(n // 6 + 1):` / `for b in range((n - 6*a) // 9 + 1):` / `if (n - 6*a - 9*b) % 20 == 0:` / `return True` is literally 3300 times fewer iterations (265 instead of 894,916).

Comment: I think I'm somewhat grasping the math here, @HughBothwell, but c does not appear to be defined now. After the for loop for b, I added `for c in range ((n-6*a-9*b)//20 + 1)` and then used `if 6*a + 9*b + 20*c == n`. Now I get the answer "43" which is what I had already brute-force calculated as correct!

Comment: @devonjones: doing another for-loop for c is unnecessary; c is implicitly defined as `(n - 6*a - 9*b) / 20` which only has an integer answer if `(n - 6*a - 9*b) % 20 == 0`, so you can read the last clause as `if (c has an integer solution): return True`. We don't need to know the _value_ of c, only that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've used itertools.product to avoid the 3 deep nesting of for loops. This means I can easily break out of the loop

```
from itertools import product, count

v = [6,9,20]
min_v = min(v)
miss = 0

for n in count(1):
    for w in product(range(n), repeat=len(v)):
        if sum(i * j for i, j in zip(v, w)) == n:
            break
    else:
        miss = n
    if n == miss + min_v:
        break

print miss
```

This does test a bunch of cases that aren't necessary as noticed by @Joran in the comments on the question. The following way avoids those cases by setting up the `product` slightly differently

```
from itertools import product, count

v = [6,9,20]
min_v = min(v)
miss = 0

for n in count(1):
    for w in product(*(range(1 + n // i) for i in v)):
        if sum(i * j for i, j in zip(v, w)) == n:
            break
    else:
        miss = n
    if n == miss + min_v:
        break

print miss
```

If we use the step parameter to range, it can be further simplified to this

```
from itertools import product, count

v = [6,9,20]
min_v = min(v)
miss = 0

for n in count(1):
    for w in product(*(range(0, n + 1, i) for i in v)):
        if sum(w) == n:
            break
    else:
        miss = n
    if n == miss + min_v:
        break

print miss
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I don't think you're going to be able to explain `itertools.product`, the splat operator, and generator expressions to someone who's reluctant to learn about `bool`.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this won't work in Python 2.5. For one thing, most of the combinatorial stuff in `itertools` was added in 2.6.

Comment: Sure you did: `sum(w) == n` is a bool. Maybe `if sum(w) - n:` `pass` `else:` `break`? :)

Comment: Ah, you know I meant "bool as a flag"

Comment: I would be happy to learn about any of these things. They're simply beyond the purview of what I had learned when I began writing my original code. I would still appreciate it if someone explained the merits/failings of said code & where to go with it, rather than handing me code I didn't begin myself. If this weren't a homework assignment for me to conceptually understand "how to make an algorithm at all"— and rather a problem I posed for an immediate practical application— then trust me, I'd take gnibbler's answer and run with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized version, which will work for any number of pieces:

```
def solution_exists(amt, pieces, i=None):
    """
    Return True if any whole multiples of pieces[:i+1] sum to amt, else False
    """
    if i is None:
        i = len(pieces) - 1   # start with last item
    p = pieces[i]
    if i:
        return any(solution_exists(amt - p*k, pieces, i-1) for k in range(amt // p + 1))
    else:
        return amt % p == 0

def find_max_unbuyable(pieces):
    least = min(pieces)
    n = 0
    last_unsolved = None
    consecutive = 0
    while consecutive < least:
        n += 1
        if solution_exists(n, pieces):
            consecutive += 1
        else:
            last_unsolved = n
            consecutive = 0
    return last_unsolved

def main():
    pieces = [6, 9, 20]
    max_unbuyable = find_max_unbuyable(pieces)
    print("Largest number of McNuggets that cannot be bought in exact quantity: {n}".format(n=max_unbuyable))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

`find_max_unbuyable` is pretty straight-forward; it's pretty much step-for-step from the description of the problem.

`solution_exists` is more involved; it is a recursive satisfiability test. For each pack, starting with the last one and working to the first, it figures out the maximum possible number which can be bought (`amt // p`) and the remaining number of pieces to buy (`amt - p*k`). It then calls itself against the reduced sub-problem. If the sub-problem is solved, then the problem is solved, and `any` short-cuts the evaluation and returns True. For the base case (`i == 0`, we are looking at the last pack) we return True iff the remaining amount is evenly divisible by p (`amt % p == 0`).

There are two benefits to writing `solution_exists` in this way: first, it is a more efficient solution (iterating as few times as possible, doing the last piece as modulo divison instead of another iteration, short-circuiting as soon as a solution is found); second, because it is recursive, it will happily operate on arbitrarily large numbers of packages.